# Javascript - on scroll if div is visible not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `3 div` sections on my page, `header`, `content` and and a `footer` and a each of them has a `carousel`. I need to check somehow which one of them is fully visible so that I can perform action accordingly. I should when one of them is fully visible enable going through `carousel` images in the section that is currently fully visible. I have tried with this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var coverImage = $('.magazine-hero'),
      carousel = $('.carousel'),
      carouselVisible = isElementInViewport(carousel),
      coverEventBinded = false;
      carouselEventBinded = false;

  if (carouselVisible && !carouselEventBinded ) {
    $(document).on('keyup', null, 'right', function(){ $('.next').click(); });
    $(document).on('keyup', null, 'left', function(){ $('.previous').click(); });
    carouselEventBinded = true;
  }

  window.onscroll = function() {
    coverVisible = isElementInViewport(coverImage);
    carouselVisible = isElementInViewport(carousel);

    if (coverVisible && !coverEventBinded ) {
      $(document).on('keyup', null, 'right', forward);
      $(document).on('keyup', null, 'left', back);
      coverEventBinded = true;
    }

    if (carouselVisible && !carouselEventBinded ) {
      $(document).on('keyup', null, 'right', function(){ $('.next').click(); });
      $(document).on('keyup', null, 'left', function(){ $('.previous').click(); });
      carouselEventBinded = true;
    }
  }
});

function isElementInViewport(el) {
  var rect = el[0].getBoundingClientRect();

  return rect.bottom > rect.height &&
        rect.top < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right > 0 &&
        rect.left < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth);
}
```

But that doesn't work, because when I am scrolling down and the upper div is still visible I am able to navigate carousels of both sections. How can I fix that?

**Update**

I have updated my script, now I am trying to see if the cover is visible and then bind key events for navigating covers, and if it is not visible I am unbiding the events for covers navigation, and biding the events for carousels:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var coverImage = $('.magazine-hero'),
      headerCarousel = $('.header-carousel'),
      headerCarouselVisible = isElementInViewport(headerCarousel),
      coverEventBinded = false,
      carouselEventBinded = false;

  if (headerCarouselVisible && !carouselEventBinded ) {
    $(document).on('keyup', null, 'right', function(){ $('.next').click(); });
    $(document).on('keyup', null, 'left', function(){ $('.previous').click(); });
    carouselEventBinded = true;
  }

  window.onscroll = function() {
    coverVisible = isElementInViewport(coverImage);
    headerCarouselVisible = isElementInViewport(headerCarousel);

console.log('Cover visible ' + coverVisible);
console.log('Event binded ' + coverEventBinded);

    if (coverVisible && !coverEventBinded) {
      $(document).unbind('keyup', null, 'right', function(){ $('.next').click(); });
      $(document).unbind('keyup', null, 'left', function(){ $('.previous').click(); });
      $(document).on('keyup', null, 'right', forward);
      $(document).on('keyup', null, 'left', back);
      coverEventBinded = true;
      carouselEventBinded = false;
    }
    else {
      $(document).unbind('keyup', null, 'right', forward);
      $(document).unbind('keyup', null, 'left', back);
      $(document).on('keyup', null, 'right', function(){ $('.next').click(); });
      $(document).on('keyup', null, 'left', function(){ $('.previous').click(); });
      carouselEventBinded = true;
      coverEventBinded = false;
    }
  }
});


function isElementInViewport(el) {
  var rect = el[0].getBoundingClientRect();

console.log('Bottom ' + rect.bottom);
console.log('Height ' + rect.height);
console.log('Client height ' + document.documentElement.clientHeight);
console.log('Window height ' + window.innerHeight);

  return rect.bottom > 0 &&
        rect.top < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right > 0 &&
        rect.left < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth);
}
```

The issue I have now, is that sometimes even when the bottom is a minus value or less than 0, I get true for `coverVisible`. And also sometimes the coverEventBinded is true when it shouldn't be true. I am not sure what is wrong with the script, that it behaves this way?

Comment: what do you mean by "fully visible" ? it's either visible or not I think

Comment: By fully visible I mean that you can see it in its full height

Comment: I am not hiding divs

Comment: ahh you mean the user will scroll and they're now seeing header,content or footer and you want to check which one ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that

Comment: in that case duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

Comment: Does your problem is that you may have 2 carousels fully in viewport at the same time?

Comment: @niceman I have already seen this solution and have tried to work with it, but the above mentioned scenario happens to me, because I have 3 sections it is a different case scenario, so that answer didn't help me

Comment: no, at no point two of the sections are visible with their full height in the viewport

Comment: So please, clarify this *«But that doesn't work, because when I am scrolling down and the upper div is still visible I am able to navigate carousels of both sections.»*

Comment: hmm so when the upper div is visible but in small size, you want it to stop, ok the answer isn't a duplicate(you should mention your findings next time) but the function `getBoundingClientRect` can still be used

Comment: Well, when I scroll and still see the bottom part of the upper div, and the upper half of the bottom div, I can navigate carousels of both sections

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette he wants the carousel that occupies the most of the viewport to play even when there are others occupying a small section of the viewport

Comment: @niceman exactly, I want the one that is visible the most to have enabled navigation

Comment: I think you should iterate the `.carousel` elements in `isFullyVisible(el)`... You actually run the function on the collection of all three elements. The function should then return a array of boolean like (false,true,false)... This way you'd know exactly which is visible. It can be done many ways.... probably.

Comment: You have to more clearly define fully visible.

Comment: But the boolean you get from `isFullyVisible(el)` can't indicate exactly which is visible because you run the function on an element collection. So that is what you have to fix ;)

Comment: May I suggest https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport :) I think `tolerance` is what you want

Comment: @niceman: good plugin suggestion, but OP would also have to run the test on each carousel instead of the `.carousel` collection. So it doesn't solve anything about the issue.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette hmm OP can call `.inViewPort` on `$('.carousel')` but hmmm yes you're right

Comment: yes, I will fix that

Comment: ok I think I found exactly what you want, check it out https://github.com/andyexeter/most-visible